# How to convert json to excel and vice versa with kept structure

Tags: python

I wanted to convert json into XLS and vice versa. Tried in Python, as well as multiple online tools but the structure got changed of `json`.
My python script, receives `json` file as an input and convert it into excel sheet. 
After making some changes in the values, I will give my excel as an input so that I can get the "JSON" file again with the same format as it was initially.

I tried with below codes -

A) -  For converting JSON to excel

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(r"MyJsonFile.json")
print(df)
df.to_excel(r"MyExcelFile.xlsx", index= False)
```

B) - For converting Excel to JSON

```py
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile(r"MyExcelFile.xlsx")
df  = pd.read_excel(xls)
print(df)
df.to_json(r"MyJsonFile.json")
```

Json is -

```
{
  "apiVersion": "3.3",
  "extensions": [
    {
      "name": "systemDetail",
      "value": "ThinkPad"
    },
    {
      "name": "serialNumber",
      "value": "KK/KKK-jej_"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-save-a-Python-Dictionary-to-CSV-file

Comment: what does the changed structure look like?